# Find the matrix of the total derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$ f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}) $$

for $(x,y) \not= (0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$. I'm trying to find the matrix of the total derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$. I think it's just $\begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ but I'm not sure. Here is my reasoning:

For all $\hat{h} \in \Bbb R^2$ we have

$\begin{align*}
f( (0,0) + \hat{h} ) - f( (0,0) ) &= f( \hat{h} ) \\
&= ||\hat{h}||^2 \sin{1/||\hat{h}||}\\
&\leq ||\hat{h}||^2
\end{align*}$

Since $||\hat{h}||^2 = o(||\hat{h}||)$, we have

$$ \lim_{\hat{h} \to (0,0)} \frac{f(\hat{h})}{||h||} = 0 $$

Thus the total derivative is the zero function $\hat{0} : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$. So its matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Is this correct? If so, how exactly should I interpret the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$? Does it have to do with the fact that the tangent plane to the graph of $f$ at $(0,0)$ is $z=0$ (assuming this is correct)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is fine. Consider the graph map given by $F(x,y) = (x,y,f(x,y)$. We know that the differential $DF(p): T_pU \to T_{F(p)}\Gamma(f|_U)$ where $\Gamma(f|_U)$ is the graph of $f$ but restricted to $U$ i.e the tangent plane at $F(0,0) = \textbf{0}$ is the image of $DF(0,0)$.

$$\textbf{im}(DF(0,0)) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ f_x(0,0) = 0 & f_y(0,0) = 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x & y & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

[image]

and this corresponds to the plane $z = 0$. Without the "matrix" approach, you can use the fact that the linearization $L(x,y)$ of $z = f(x,y)$ is the best linear approximation to the graph of $f$ i.e;

\begin{align*} L(x,y) &= f_x(0,0) x + f_y(0,0) y + f(0,0) \\& = f(0,0) \\ & = 0 \end{align*}

Hence, $f(x,y) - L(x,y) \approx \epsilon$ if $(x,y)$ is sufficiently close to the origin, and so $z = f(x,y) = 0$ is the tangent plane.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer. One small question--I thought in this case the partial derivatives $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0$ don't exist. This is because at $y=0$, $f_x = 2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)$ which has no limit as $x$ approaches $0$. Or do $f_x$ and $f_y$ represent something different?

Comment: I think you were confusing that step with problems in which you try to show that a function is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: Ah, now I see where I went wrong. At $(0,0)$, the partial derivatives exist, but are not continuous.

Comment: Yes. This is the example in which you see partials don't have to be continuous for a function to be differentiable.